# How to run a command on the startup of an xterm?

Tags: startup, xterm

How can I run a command on xterm startup i.e. when an xterm terminal is launched a the command is already executed?

I have edited the .bashrc file to add this line:

xterm "ls"

But this does not work.

Please suggest what should I do to acheive this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the `bash` manual, `~/.bashrc` is used for interactive shells. xterm runs a shell, so perhaps your "does not work" causes a chain of xterm's.

The xterm program sets these [environment variables](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h2-ENVIRONMENT) which are useful for scripting: `XTERM_VERSION` and `XTERM_SHELL`.  In your `~/.bashrc` file, you could use the former to run the `xterm -ls` once only:

```
if [[ -z "$XTERM_VERSION" ]]
then
    xterm -hold -e ls &
fi
```

which seems to be what you are asking for:

- it would run an xterm if not run from an existing xterm
- it prevents the xterm from closing when the `ls` is done.

A more useful-seeming way of showing an `ls` on shell startup would be to run `ls` in each shell as it is started (for that case, you do not need run a separate `xterm`).  Again, you can use environment variables to do this *once* (in case you run `bash` to make a subshell):

```
if [[ -z "$XTERM_ONCE" ]]
then
    export XTERM_ONCE=$(date)
    ls
fi
```

Comment: xterm has set this since 2005 - see (changelog)[http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_202]

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
-e /bin/bash -login
```

> **-e command [arguments]**
>
> Run the command with its command-line arguments in the rxvt window;
>   also sets the window title and icon name to be the basename of the
>   program being executed if neither -title (-T) nor -n are given on the
>   command line. If this option is used, it must be the last on the
>   command-line. If there is no -e option then the default is to run the
>   program specified by the SHELL environment variable or, failing that,
>   sh(1).

http://linux.die.net/man/1/rxvt

Comment: where do you type this -e /bin/bash -login ? I mean in which file ?

Comment: These are apparently command-line arguments for the `xterm` or `rxvt` invocation. If you don't start `xterm` from a command-line prompt (in which case you are already running an `xterm` instance in many environments!) this seems less useful.

Comment: `xterm -e /bin/sh -c "hello -g Example"` worked for me :)